# Conditional Formatting between dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to create a conditional formatting rule with the following logic:

```
IF (Cell A2 is between the values of A8 and A10, then fill current cell Yellow)
Where Cell A2, A8, and A10 are dates.
```

For example:

```
Cell A2 = 1/3/2019
Cell A8 = 1/1/2019
Cell A10 = 1/31/2019
The current cell should fill to yellow.
```

I've tried using the following:

```
IF(A2 >=A8) + IF(A2 <= A10)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current formula solves as True when either of the conditions are correct. You need a formula that is True when they both are correct.

```
=AND(A2>=A8, A2<=A10)
```